# Ruby regexp: capture the path of url

Tags: ruby, regex

From any URL I want to extract its path.

For example:

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Path: questions/ask

It shouldn't be difficult:

```
url[/(?:\w{2,}\/).+/]
```

But I think I use a wrong pattern for 'ignore this' ('?:' - doesn't work). What is the right way?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would suggest you don't do this with a regular expression, and instead use the built in URI lib:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI::parse('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')

puts uri.path # results in: /questions/ask
```

It has a leading slash, but thats easy to deal with =)

Comment: I agree, using the built in class is best. However, if you are interested in learning how to parse URI's for academic reasons, check out the [source code to lib/uri/common.rb](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/blob/master/lib/uri/common.rb#L483) -- I've linked to Rubinius' source code because I find it easy to read. The (very complex) regular expressions are at the top of the file, absolute URI is at line 188.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex in this case, which is faster than `URI.parse`:

```
s = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'

s[s[/.*?\/\/[^\/]*\//].size..-1]
# => "questions/ask"  (6,8 times faster)

s[/\/(?!.*\.).*/]
# => "/questions/ask" (9,9 times faster, but with an extra slash)
```

But if you don't care with the speed, use **uri**, as ctcherry showed, is more readable.

Comment: If you want correctness (e.g. `s = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions//ask/stuff'`), use `URI.parse`. Don't worry about the speed difference until you have found URI parsing to be a real bottleneck in your code.

Comment: A negative lookahead! Wow, crazy! I have to go figure out how that one works.

Comment: In a development environment a common URL may be `http://localhost/test`. The negative lookahead expression will fail.

Comment: I would now strongly recommend one to use `URI.parse` regardless of such speed improvements of the regex version. `URI.parse` is much more solid and will work on any edges cases as @ClintPachl noted.

Answer (score -1):

The approach presented by ctcherry is perfectly correct, but I prefer to use `request.fullpath` instead of including the URI library in the code. Just call `request.fullpath` in your views or controllers. But be careful, if you have any GET parameters in your URL it will be catched, in this case a use a `split('?').first`

Comment: -1 - OP asked neither about Rails nor getting current request URL