# Ruby/Rails : Get url extension with URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, uri

currently i'm have a bit problem to parse URL using URI

i've tried to use this code :

```
uri = URI::parse(Model.first.media)
#<URI::HTTPS https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/model/media/41/cdbb21cc-1c59-4aa3-92ec-917e7237a850.mp4>

uri.path
"/model/media/41/cdbb21cc-1c59-4aa3-92ec-917e7237a850.mp4"

File.basename(Model.first.media, '.mp4')
"cdbb21cc-1c59-4aa3-92ec-917e7237a850.mp4"
```

but i'm still confused to get `path` without `/` as first char in example `model/media/41/cdbb21cc-1c59-4aa3-92ec-917e7237a850.mp4` and get only the path without domain and the file in example `model/media/41`

do i must using regex to get above output ? or URI can handle this ?

note:

i've found how to get url extension without first char based on this question [Ruby regexp: capture the path of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129574/ruby-regexp-capture-the-path-of-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI class helps break apart URLs into components and gives you methods like

```
[:scheme, :userinfo, :host, :port, :path, :query, :fragment]
```

If you simply need to get rid of the first slash it's simple as this with no regex.

```
uri.path[1..-1] #gives all string characters except the 0 index.
```

But you could probably even get away with:

```
Model.first.media.split('.com/').last # don't even need URI parse.
```

For last part of your question you can do:

```
File.dirname(uri.path) # will return => "/model/media/41"

File.dirname(uri.path)[1..-1] # if you want to remove leading /
```

Comment: Hi, i really appreciate your help sir :). But may ask you, which one is better ?.

Comment: Best practice is to use only what you need.  If you only need to operate on a string, use the last option.  If you need to do something else with a URI object, then use one.

Comment: and with my other question, can you help it too ? currently i've tried this code 
`File.dirname(uri) + "/" + File.basename(Model.first.media, '.mp4') + ".m3u8"`

To change recorded format file in my database, in example previously my file is `play/media/41/my_video.mp4 `, then i want to change it to `.m3u8` so i'm using above code

Comment: if you just want to change the extension name, again, just use basic string methods:  `"play/media/41/my_video.mp4".gsub('.mp4', '.m3u8')` but that assumes `.mp4` will only be the extension and not anywhere else in the string.  Should be fine if the filenames use normal conventions.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it's really help me :) . but can i ask one more question. How to get url without filename extension, primary domain and '/' as first char.

url = https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/model/media/41/cdbb21cc-1c59-4aa3-92ec-917e7237a850.mp4

expected_url = `model/media/41/cdbb21cc-1c59-4aa3-92ec-917e7237a850`

currently i'm using this one `File.dirname(uri) + "/" + File.basename(Model.first.media, '.mp4')` to get expected_url